# What is the simplest way to implement CDC in a monolithic Django project with MySQL DB?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, change-data-capture

I want to implement the logic below in my monolithic (not microservice) Django project and its MySQL DB:

1. The Django server changes data of table A in the MySQL db.
2. The CDC tool (?) captures the change and callbacks (?) the Django server.
3. The Django server updates table B (which is for saving statistic data) using the changed data of table A.

There are many tables like "table A" currently and I will create other tables like "table B" (for statistics) in the MySQL DB, so CDC is needed to keep consistency among such tables. Note that I will not write triggers or stored procedures in the MySQL db because my team want to avoid using them.

What is the simplest way to implement CDC in my project?

Comment: Django signals: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/signals/